# Create Bell Curve in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, bell-curve

I am trying to create Bell Curve from data, i.e.

`x = number of shoes`
`y = number of records`

From the data, most records, i.e. women have one pair of shoes, so 1 would be the center of the x axis.

How to approach this? Here is what I have so far

[image]

#### Data Structure

[image]

Comment: Your data structure is a little unclear. Do you have a list of people where each row has a count of the number of shoes or do you have a list of shoes with each row describing the identity of the owner? For the first case just right click the pill for the number of shoes and choose Create: Bins. Drag bins to the x axis and drop the number of records onto y axis.

Comment: @matt_black `list of people where each row has a count of the number of shoes` I shall try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put "Pair of Shoes" on the columns shelf. Change it do a dimension. I would leave the data type as a number and make it continuous.

Then put SUM(Number of Records) on the rows shelf, and make sure it is continuous.

You'll see a distribution, but it won't look like a bell curve

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this.  One of the fastest ways is probably to turn "pairs of shoes" into a text dimension.  There are a couple of ways to do that, this **[link](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/getting-total-count-distinct)** should help.

Use the bar graph.  Pairs of shoes becomes the dimensional entry.  You can then use the [count distinct](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/getting-total-count-distinct) feature:

Comment: I will try this soon